# What does $\uparrow$ mean in the context?

Tags: convergence-divergence, notation

The set up is as follows: 
"Let $f_n, f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions such that $f_n \uparrow f, n \rightarrow \infty$."
I know what it means that $f_n \rightarrow f, n \rightarrow \infty$, but can anyone explain the meaning when the $\uparrow$ is used?

Comment: Likely monotone increasing. Not necessarily strictly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f_n \uparrow f$ means that $f_n \to f$ and $f_n$ is a monotone increasing sequence i.e. $f_{n+1}(x) \geq f_n(x)$ for every $n,x$.

Comment: Does this generalize such that I instead of $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$ could write (a bit more informative) that $\frac{1}{n} \downarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @J.Goles Yes, that's standard notation too.